# how to wrap a matching set of html with a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a heading... h3
followed by a bunch of p tags... then another h3 tag. Notice how the last one doesnt have another h3 at the bottom... so the answer would need to take that into account.

I'd like to wrap the entire section after the h3 and before the next h3 in a div

ie:

```
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <p>some content</p>
    <p>more content</p>
    <ul><li>item</li></ul>

    <h3>hello again</h3>
    <p>no more</p>
```

would become...

```
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <div class="expander">
    <p>some content</p>
    <p>more content</p>
    <ul><li>item</li></ul>
    </div>

    <h3>hello again</h3>
    <div class="expander"><p>no more</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var h3 = $('h3');
var wrapper = "<div class='expander'>";

h3.filter(':first').nextUntil('h3').wrapAll(wrapper);
h3.filter(':last').next('p').wrap(wrapper);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ALX5y/)

Comment: this doesn't quite work... add a few more sets of h3 follows by content and it only applies to the first and last. I need it to do ALL the h3 sets

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `p` element which comes after a `h3` element and then group all `p` elements coming after it like

```
$('h3 + p').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(p)').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="expander"></div>');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wbuuv/)

Answer (score 0):

Use  wrap b/w all element with in h3

```
 $("h3").filter(function(){   // to select all h3 element
$(this).nextUntil("h3").wrapAll('<div class="expander">');// select one h3 element to other h3 element and wrap the all element 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmv8V/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.each() of Jquery like below to put a wrapper after each h3

```
         var h3 = $("h3");
         var wrapper = $("<div id='wrapper'>");

         $.each(h3,function(){

           $(this).nextUntil("h3").wrapAll(wrapper);
         });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76ddp/)